# Is it possible to combine if else statement with switch case statement in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, switch-statement

I've been doing this program in Matlab for about 4 weeks now, to calculate the sun position on given date, time and location. Now i am trying to calculate the leap year on a given year, but seems to get no solution. This just part of my code:

```
day=str2num(aw(1,1:2)); %To calculate day number (nth day of the year)
month=str2num(aw(1,4:5));
year=str2num(aw(1,4:5));

if mod(year,100)==0 

switch month
    case 1
        dn=day;
    case 2
        dn=31+day;
    case 3
        dn=59+day;
    case 4
        dn=90+day;
    case 5
        dn=120+day;
    case 6
        dn=151+day;
    case 7
        dn=181+day;
    case 8
        dn=212+day;
    case 9
        dn=243+day;
    case 10
        dn=273+day;
    case 11
        dn=304+day;
    case 12
        dn=334+day;   
end;

    elseif mod(year,4)==0 && mod(year,400)~=0

    switch month
        case 1
            dn=day;
        case 2
            dn=31+day;
        case 3
            dn=60+day;
        case 4
            dn=91+day;
        case 5
            dn=121+day;
        case 6
            dn=152+day;
        case 7
            dn=182+day;
        case 8
            dn=213+day;
        case 9
            dn=244+day;
        case 10
            dn=274+day;
        case 11
            dn=305+day;
        case 12
            dn=335+day;   
    end;
```

and the rest are just the formula to calculate the sun position. Is it possible to combine an `if`-`else` statement with an `switch`/`case` statement? Appreciate if somebody help me because I am not really a programmer. Just try to push myself on this calculation using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but possibly a better way of doing things. Rather than trying to calculate the day of year by hand, you should use MATLAB's builtin datenum function, which is very powerful for this kind of thing. For instance, suppose you have a date 23/11/2008. You can determine the day of year like so:

```
doy = datenum(2008,23,11) - datenum(2008,0,0);
```

`datenum(2008,23,11)` calculates the number of days from year 0 to the target date. `datenum(2008,0,0)` calculates the number of days from year 0 to 31/12/2007. If you subtract these two numbers, you get the day of year of the target date. This way you don't have to worry about leap years and all of the intricacies involved, but rather just let MATLAB handle them for you.

Comment: Thank you MrAzzaman, I very much appreciate your help but that will work if you know the target date. But in my case (which I forgot to mentioned), I need to ask user to enter their date of interest, and so I need to calculate the number of days. Before that I need to calculate whether the year is leap year or not. My idea is to use the if-else and switch-case statement. but I dont know how. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: It's no different to what you've got currently. Just do `datenum(year,month,day) - datenum(year,0,0);`

Comment: Alhamdulillah, I tried the datenum function in my program, and it works. Thanks again MrAzzaman.